# Ruby on Rails - Active Record Query - Return items that only have an image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm redeveloping a site that has an image slider on the home page that shows 5 of the latest news stories, however, I only want it to show the latest 5 stories that have at least one image in the images table.

So my question is, how to I modify the below to return five records with images:

```
@slider_stories = Story.published.all(:limit => 50, :include => [:images])
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that

```
@slider_stories = Story.published.all(:limit => 50, :include => [:images], :conditions => "DISTINCT(stories.id), stories.*, images.*")
```

or

```
@slider_stories_ids = Image.all(:select => "DISTINCT(story_id)").map(&:story_id)
@slider_stories = Story.published.all(:limit => 50, :include => [:images], :conditions => {:id => @lider_stories_ids})
```

Comment: The first gives an SQL invalid group function because of the inner joins I believe, not got the second one working yet (returns empty result) but I believe I'm getting there. Thanks.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT `stories`.id FROM `stories`  LEFT OUTER JOIN `images` ON `images`.item_id = `stories`.id AND `images`.item_type = 'Story' WHERE (COUNT(images.item_id) > 0) AND (`stories`.`aasm_state` = 'published')  ORDER BY stories.created_at DESC LIMIT 5

Comment: @Tom, there should be `map`: `@slider_stories_ids = Image.all(:select => "DISTINCT(story_id)").map(&:story_id)`

Comment: That's done it! Without the map it was bringing back NULL values. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Tom, Also try this `@slider_stories = Story.published.all(:limit => 50, :include => [:images], :conditions => "DISTINCT(stories.id), stories.*, images.*")`